# Unable to properly set a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In 1 file I have (this is my service file @ angular):

```
var columnNames = [];
var rowData;

return {

          setRowData: function (data) {
              rowData = data;
          },

          getRowData: function () {
              return rowData;
          },

          getColumn: function () {
              return columnNames;
          },

          addColumn: function (col) {
              columnNames.push({
                  name: col,
                  field: col
              });
          },

// etc
```

In another file, I call the set method when an event triggers (a controller file):

```
    var onParamComplete = function (response) {
        demoUtils.addColumn(response.data);
    };

    var onRunComplete = function (response) {
        // response.data is an array
        demoUtils.setRowData(response.data);
    };
```

Finally in a second controller I set it to the scope so that I could view the value in a data binding template:

```
      $scope.r = demoUtils.getColumn();
      $scope.q = demoUtils.getRowData();
```

And I am displaying it on a HTML file with

```
{{ r }}
{{ q }}
```

For some reason, the value of getColumn() method is working correctly but my getRowData() method is not.

I debugged the value in onRunComplete() and saw that an assignment is happening correctly, but my getRowData() is not seeing the update. It is also not executing when a place a breakpoint there, but for some reason $scope.r is changing and $scope.q isn't when both of their assignment breakpoints are not triggering.

Comment: Race condition? Are you sure `onRunComplete()` is getting called before `getRowData()`? Also, would it be possible for you to set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your rowData variable first

```
var columnNames = [];
var rowData = [];
```

It would be also easier to help you if you created plunkr example also...

You could also try angular.copy

```
setRowData: function (data) {
    rowData = angular.copy(data);
},
```